# I am not able to retrieve the https response when making a call to another feature file while using conditions to decide which scenario to execute

Tags: karate

I have three feature file which does following things in my use case -

*main.feature *-> has the script for main feature and starting point of the flow.

*redirect.feature *-> It is a caller feature that simply redirects the flow to execute an appropriate scenario from the next feature file based on the env provided(Example - login.feature)

*login.feature *-> Three login scenario that has steps specific to the env.

**Content of main.feature**

```
Background: 
* def userType = user 
Given call read(classpath:feature/redirect.feature) {userType : #'(userType)'}

Scenario Outline:
* print response 
Then match response contains 'someValidation'

Example: 
|user   | 
|manager|
```

**Content of redirect.feature**

```
Scenario: Redirect to an appropriate login mechanism based on the env

if(env == 'qa') karate.call(classpath:feature/login.feature@QALogin) {userType : #'(userType)'}
if(env == 'dev') karate.call(classpath:feature/login.feature@DevLogin) {userType : #'(userType)'}
if(env == 'local') karate.call(classpath:feature/login.feature@LocalLogin) {userType : #'(userType)'}
```

**Content of login.feature**

```
Background:
Given url http://myapplication.com

@QALogin
Scenario:
When path 'userpath'
And request {userType: #'(userType)'}
And method post
Then responseStatus == '200'

@DevLogin
Sceanrio:
When path 'userpath'
And request {userType: #'(userType)', password: 'test@123', agent:'browser'}
And method post
Then responseStatus == '200'

@LocalLogin
Scenario:
When path 'userpath'
And request {userType: #'(userType)', a:'gherkin', b:'somevalue'}
And header {Agent:'LocalAgent'}
And method post
Then responseStatus == '200'
```

When I run the main.feature file, the flow goes to redirect.feature and then based on the env passed via VMArgs, it does execute the respective scenario of the next feature (login.feature) file.

It all works fine, but instead of printing the actual login response, it prints the following
{userType : manager}. Therefore due to this, I am not able to perform the next course of action based on the response I receive.

**Question **-> It actually prints the embedded expression in json format but does not print the actual response from the login feature. What is wrong that I am doing here?

I tried to do even replace with **karate.call** with **call read** but that does not work either. It does all fine but no way to figure out to capture the response of login steps.

Please guide.

Comment: I see a typo `Sceanrio` - and if you print wrongly, json will look wrong: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#print - otherwise your example is too complicated for stack overflow, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Fixed the typo here. However in actual the issue is still not resolved for me.

Comment: maybe someone else can help, all the best

Comment: @PeterThomas I had to get rid of the redirect.feature file and then called the actual login.feature from the main.feature file itself by adding a tag (@Login-)+karate.env which would replace the value of karate.env at the run time to whatever we pass from arg line. Example - 

In main.feature file
`Background:
* def loginPage = 'classpath:feature/login.feature@Login-' + karate.env
Given call read(loginPage) {userType : #'(userType)'}`

In the login.feature file, each of the scenario were then tagged with `@Login-QA, @Login-Dev, @Login-Local` respectively